# Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfNull itextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to insert a cover page on a pdf. Closing the stamper.Close() throws the following exception

```
    System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfNull' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary'.at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.Close(IDictionary`2 moreInfo)
```

What am I not doing right?

```
        PdfReader cover = new PdfReader(coverpage);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);            
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));

        stamper.InsertPage(1, cover.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        PdfContentByte page1 = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
        PdfImportedPage page = stamper.GetImportedPage(cover, 1);
        page1.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

        stamper.Close();
        cover.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

Comment: I imagine either cover or reader are returning you a null pdf

Comment: Please share the pdf in question. It also might be missing support of the PDF null object in certain situations.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hPmJ3yQizSeYyR3DuH38JWLg_6RtvSSi/view?usp=sharing